# Kafka JDBC Sink- removing \u0000 from Kafka messages

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Kindly find the below Kafka message example and Jdbc sink Kafka connect config for reference

##Kafka Message:

```
{
  "col1":{
    "string":"value1"
   },
  "col2":{
    "string":"value2 \u0000"
   },
  "col3":{
    "string":"value3"
   }
}
```

###Sink config:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "mode": "bulk",
    "table.name.format": "<Schema_name>.${topic}",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "<topic_name>",
    "name": "<topic_name>",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://<IP_address>:<port_number>/<db_name>?user=<user_name>&password=<password>",
    "insert.mode": "insert"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I recall this being an open issue in the jdbc connector github repo

Comment: Kafka Message:


{
  "col1":{
    "string":"value1"
   },
  "col2":{
    "string":"value2 \u0000"
   },
  "col3":{
    "string":"value3"
   }
}

Comment: Sink config: 

{
 "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
 "mode": "bulk",
 "table.name.format": "<Schema_name>.${topic}",
 "auto.evolve": "true",
 "tasks.max": "1",
 "topics": "<topic_name>",
 "name": "<topic_name>",
 "auto.create": "true",
 "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://<IP_address>:<port_number>/<db_name>?user=<user_name>&password=<password>",
 "insert.mode": "insert"
}

Comment: Connect-distributed.properties:

added parameter: 

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable= false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable= false

Comment: Sink Error: 
Error: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0x00 Call getNextException to see other errors in the 
batch.\norg.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR:invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0x00\norg.postgresql.util.PSQLException:rror: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0x00\n\n]tat
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.getAllMessageException(JdbcSinkTask.java:150)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:102)\n\t

Comment: @OneCricketeer Kindly find the above message format, sink config, parameters added in connect-distributed.properties and the error received while loading data into PostgreSQL using JDBC sink

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include formatted text rather than add code/config in comments.

Comment: Related - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/1216#issue-1299731914

Comment: I didn't find solution in above github link as well. Still trying to resolve the issue.

Comment: You need to fork the project and patch the code on your own from this PR https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/pull/1264